# two dimensional list comprehension , Python 3

Tags: python

i have Two dimensional list

```
[[0.5 , 0.1, 0.75]
 [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75]
 [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75]]
```

what i want , if value <=0.5 it will be converted to 0 ,  if value >0.5 it will be converted to 1

```
[[0 , 0, 1]
 [0 , 0, 1]
 [0 , 0, 1]]
```

how to do this as simple as possible , like using list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
[[0 if i<=0.5 else 1 for i in x ] for x in lst] #where lst is the original list

o/p : [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually trying to round the numbers in list. For this, use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) with a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [[0.5 , 0.1, 0.75],
       [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75],
       [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75]]

print([[round(y) for y in x] for x in lst])
# [[0, 0, 1],
#  [0, 0, 1],
#  [0, 0, 1]]
```

Or using `map` + list-comprehension:

```
print([list(map(round, x)) for x in lst])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = [[0.5 , 0.1, 0.75],
        [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75],
        [0.5 , 0.1, 0.75]]

print([[1 if x > .5 else 0 for x in row] for row in rows])
```